# mapReduce inline results with java mongodb driver 3.2

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-java

How to have inline results from a mapReducet with the mongodb java driver 3.2?

with driver version 2.x I was doing:

```
DBColleciont coll = client.getDB(dbName).getCollection(collName);
coll.mapReduce(map, reduce, null, OutputType.INLINE, query);
```

the new 3.x driver has two *mapReduce()* methods returning *MapReduceIterable* which misses a method to specify the INLINE output mode.

```
MongoCollection<Documetn> coll = client.getDatabase(dbName).getCollection(collName)
coll
    .mapReduce(map, reduce).
    .filter(query);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found it...
I had a deeper look into mongodb's Java driver source and it seems that the INLINE output feature is implicitly accessible:

The `class MapReduceIterableImpl<TDocument, TResult>`([MapReduceIterableImpl.java](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/blob/master/driver/src/main/com/mongodb/MapReduceIterableImpl.java)), which is the default implementation of the Interface return type of `mapReduce()`,
holds a `private boolean inline` with initial value `true`.

The only place where this can ever be switched to `false` is the method `collectionName(final String collectionName)` for which the description is as follows:

> Sets the collectionName for the output of the MapReduce
>   The default action is replace the collection if it exists, to change this use action(com.mongodb.client.model.MapReduceAction).

If you never call this method on the object instance after `mapReduce()`, it will remain `true` as initialized...meaning: if there is no output collection, it must be inline.

Later on, when you access your result with `iterator(), first(), forEach(...)`  etc internally the `execute()` method gets called which hast the magic `if` condition:

```
if (inline) {
        MapReduceWithInlineResultsOperation<TResult> operation =
                new MapReduceWithInlineResultsOperation<TResult>(namespace,
                        new BsonJavaScript(mapFunction),
                        new BsonJavaScript(reduceFunction),
                        codecRegistry.get(resultClass))
                        .filter(toBsonDocument(filter))
                        .limit(limit)
                        .maxTime(maxTimeMS, MILLISECONDS)
                        .jsMode(jsMode)
                        .scope(toBsonDocument(scope))
                        .sort(toBsonDocument(sort))
                        .verbose(verbose)
                        .readConcern(readConcern);
....

} else {
        MapReduceToCollectionOperation operation =
                new MapReduceToCollectionOperation(namespace, new BsonJavaScript(mapFunction), new BsonJavaScript(reduceFunction),
                        collectionName)
                        .filter(toBsonDocument(filter))
                        .limit(limit)
                        .maxTime(maxTimeMS, MILLISECONDS)
                        .jsMode(jsMode)
                        .scope(toBsonDocument(scope))
                        .sort(toBsonDocument(sort))
                        .verbose(verbose)
                        .action(action.getValue())
                        .nonAtomic(nonAtomic)
                        .sharded(sharded)
                        .databaseName(databaseName)
                        .bypassDocumentValidation(bypassDocumentValidation);
```

...so it is instanciating `MapReduceWithInlineResultsOperation` when `collectionName()` has not been called.

I had no chance to test it because my NetBeans hates me at the moment, but I think it is pretty clear.
What do you think, did I miss something?

Would be glad if I could help you shift the code to API 3.x, great project!

Answer (score 3):

You can create the map-reduce command manually:

```
    String mapFunction = ...
    String reduceFunction = ...

    BsonDocument command = new BsonDocument();

    BsonJavaScript map = new BsonJavaScript(mapFunction);
    BsonJavaScript red = new BsonJavaScript(reduceFunction);
    BsonDocument query = new BsonDocument("someidentifier", new BsonString("somevalue"));
    command.append("mapreduce", new BsonString("mySourceCollection"));
    command.append("query", query);
    command.append("map", map);
    command.append("reduce", red);
    command.append("out", new BsonDocument("inline", new BsonBoolean(true)));

    Document result = mongoClient.getDatabase(database).runCommand(command);
```

I think this is extremely ugly, but it is the only working solution I found so far using 3.2. (... and would be very interested in a better variant, too... ;-))